# ifError got unwanted exception: password authentication failed for user "Coach"

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql

I am trying to use the command `db-migrate up` to run the migration that should create a food table, however I keep running into this error and I can't seem to find any solution.

The error:

```
[ERROR] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: password authentication failed for user "Coach"
    at module.exports (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\commands\helper\assert.js:9:14)
    at D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\commands\up.js:19:14
    at D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\db-migrate\connect.js:17:7
    at D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\driver\index.js:95:9
    at Client._connectionCallback (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\db-migrate-pg\index.js:710:7)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:325:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\FWD\Storefront-\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'

volumes:
  postgres:
```

database.json:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "driver": "pg",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "database": "storefront",
        "user": "Coach",
        "password": "password123"
    },
    "test": {
        "driver": "pg",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "database": "storefront_test",
        "user": "Coach_test",
        "password": "password123"
    }
}
```

.env:

```
const POSTGRES_HOST = 127.0.0.1
const POSTGRES_DB = storefront
const POSTGRES_USER = Coach
const POSTGRES_PASSWORD = password123
```

database.ts:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import {Pool} from 'pg'

dotenv.config()

const {
    POSTGRES_HOST, 
    POSTGRES_DB, 
    POSTGRES_USER, 
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD, 
   
}= process.env 
const client = new Pool ({
    host: POSTGRES_HOST,
    database: POSTGRES_DB,
    user: POSTGRES_USER,
    password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
})

export default client
```

I tried updating my node version to the latest version which is v18.13.0.